# How can I save file from external url Laravel public directory

Tags: php, laravel, file

I wanted to save a file from External Url which would have any kind of file like say "jpg, png, mp4 etc"

I want to save it in the public directory of Laravel App. How could I do that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

I tried the following thing, but it's saving file in my storage folder:

```
Storage::put($name, $contents);
```

Thanks

Comment: The class Storage saves in the storage folder. Use the laravel constant with the function "public_path()".

Comment: sorry? How can I save it using public_path()?

Answer (score 22):

create an img folder in public path and :

```
 $image = file_get_contents("https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Laravel_logo.png");


file_put_contents(public_path('img/a.png'), $image);
```

Answer (score 5):

use File like below

```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

and then

```
File::put(public_path(   'ANY FILE YOU WANT'    ));
```

example:

```
 File::put( public_path( 'js/a.js'), ' CONTENT ');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. How if I want to save this file: https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Laravel_logo.png ? I tried your code but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Download files from external URL after authentication.

```
 public function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) { 

    $ch = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 

    return $data; 
} 
public function downloadFile( $imgName, $url, $path )
{
    $data = $this->file_get_contents_curl( $url );
    file_put_contents( $path.$imgName, $data ); 
    echo "File downloaded!";

}
```

Code for creating a new folder based on the date.

```
   public function imgBackupFolder( $currentShop ) {

    $folderName = 'export'.DS.str_replace( '.', '_', $currentShop->shopify_domain ).DS.'images'.DS.date( 'Y_m_d' ).DS;
    return $this->createFolder( $folderName );

}
  /*
 * Create folder based on the store,date,export type
 */
private function createFolder( $folderName ) {

    try {
        $path = public_path( $folderName );

        if( !File::isDirectory( $path ) ){
            File::makeDirectory( $path, 0777, true, true );
        }
        return $path;

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Log::error( $ex->getMessage() );
    }

}
```